# trying to validate leaf nodes in expression tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I've made a boolean function that validates the leaf nodes in my expression tree. If the nodes are any operator, it returns false. Else, it should return true. It calls itself recursively...which is where the problem is I think. Can you have a boolean function be recursive? Here is my function

```
bool validate(tnode* node)
{
  if(node == NULL)
  {
    cout<<"Node is null";       
    return false;
  }
  if(node->left == NULL && node->right==NULL) 
  {
    cout<<node->key<<endl<<endl;
    if(node->key == '+' || '-' || '*' || '/')
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
  }     
  else
        validate(node->left);
        validate(node->right);      
}
```

it actually prints out the value for all my leaf nodes perfectly, which are : a b c d 2 e 3. But when I run it in my main function, it always comes back false. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(node->key == '+' || '-' || '*' || '/')
```

should be

```
if(node->key == '+' || node->key == '-' || node->key == '*' || node->key == '/')
```

Meanwhile:

```
else {
    validate(node->left);
    validate(node->right);   
} //should not miss the parenthesis
```

You probably should do something like this:

```
else{
      bool left = validate(node->left);
      bool right = validate(node->right);
      return (left && right);
}
```

Comment: can't I just just have it return true after those two validate functions have ran? If it wasn't true, then it would have broke before it finished them, right?

Comment: @user2313755 No, wrong. The return statement only leaves the current instance of the function, not the whole recursion. And you always have to return something if the function is not `void`.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't storing the results anywhere.

```
validate(node->left);
validate(node->right);
```

should be more like

```
_Bool res = validate(node->left);
```

And then do something with the result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it always returns `false` is that this expression:

```
(node->key == '+' || '-' || '*' || '/')
```

actually means

```
(node->key == '+') || ('-' != 0) ...
```

which is always true, because the `-` character does not have a zero value.

You also don't need to make that into an if-else clause, i would suggest this:

```
return !(node->key == '+' || node->key == '-'
      || node->key == '*' || node->key == '/');
```

As for the last part, i think you need to do this:

```
else
    return validate(node->left) && validate(node->right);
```